# Как выводить отрицательные элементы не сразу под значениями, а после выполнения цикла?

Tags: pascal

Как доделать код, чтобы в нем выводились отрицательные элементы не сразу под значениями, а после выполнения цикла?

```
program a1;
    uses crt;
    var a: array [1..100] of integer;
        s,d,f,i,n:integer;
begin
    clrscr;
    writeln ('wwedite razmernosti ne bolee 100');
    readln(n);
    for i:=1 to n do begin
        writeln('');
        readln(a[i]);
        if a[i] mod 3 = 0 then s:=s+1;
        if a[i] <0 then writeln (a[i]);
    end;
    writeln ('na 3 bez ostatka delitsya ', s,' elementov.');
    readkey
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln ('wwedite razmernosti ne bolee 100');

  readln(n);
  for i:=1 to n do begin
    writeln('');
    readln(a[i]);
    if a[i] mod 3 = 0 then s:=s+1;
  end;

  clrscr;
  for i:=1 to n do
    if a[i] <0 then writeln (a[i]);

  writeln ('na 3 bez ostatka delitsya ', s,' elementov.');
  readkey
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Разделите задачу на два цикла. В первом цикле for вы заполняете массив A, затем во втором цикле for вы выводите значения.

Comment: пробовал, ему побарабану. к примеру ввод 

1
2
-3
-3 // это он дописывает сам

Comment: попробуйте собрать отрицательные числа в строку и вывести после всего остального